# Are there any performance differences between singly- and doubly-linked lists?

Tags: java, data-structures

Our homework assignment asks us to prove that the Java `LinkedList` implementation is doubly-linked and not singly-linked. However, list operations such as adding elements, removing elements, and looking elements up seem to have the same complexity for both implementations, so there doesn't seem to be a way to use a performance argument to demonstrate the doubly-linked nature of Java's `LinkedList`. Anyone know of a better way to illustrate the difference between the two?

Comment: The ultimate proof is to read the source code.  But I doubt that that's what the assignment is asking for :-)

Comment: @Stephen +1 - sometimes the brute force method is best! In uni I helped my roommate with his crypto homework. The problem said it was a 3 letter Ceaser cipher. I said "what are the odds the word 'the' is in there? And there's only 17k possibilities..." his professor was not impressed, but had to give him credit since he proved how he did it. His code was also much shorter than most, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at iterating in forward or backward direction, removing the "before-last" element, and such.

Comment: We ended up looking up the before-last element. This worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's quite an easy proof -- you look at the source code and see that each node has a `.previous` pointer :)
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following nodes, single and double.

class SingleLinkedNode {
    E data;
    SingleLinkedNode next;
}

class DoubleLinkedNode {
    E data;
    DoubleLinkedNode prev;
    DoubleLinkedNode next;
}

If we want to remove from a DoubleLinkedList (assuming we have already FOUND the node, which is very different) what do we need to do?

1. Make the node before the deleted
   one point to the one after.
2. Make the node after the deleted one point to the one before.

If we want to remove from a SingleLinkedList (assuming we have already FOUND the node, which is very different) what do we need to do?

1. Make the node before the deleted one point to the one after.

You'd think that means it's even faster in a single linked list than a double.

But, how are we doing to delete the node if we don't have a reference to the one before it? We only have a reference to the next. Wouldn't we have to do a whole other search on the list just to find prev? :-O

Comment: *"Wouldn't we have to do a whole other search on the list just to find prev?"*.  Actually no.  A decent implementation of a singly linked list won't do it that way.

Comment: @Stephen How would a node single linked list have a reference to the node before it?

Comment: while you are traversing the list to find the node, maintain a reference to the previous node as well; ie the one you just called next on. so you have something like: Node tmp = head, prev; while (node.data != findItem) { prev = tmp; tmp = tmp.next; } now after loop (if item in the list) tmp is the node to remove and prev is node before, so prev.next = tmp.next;  and its gone! ;-)

Comment: and for double linked is: node.prev.next = node.next; node.next.prev = node.prev; so 1 more statement... insignificant

Comment: @Aaron - that incorporates the find into the remove. The two are different operations and should be treated independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

The Java List interface doesn't have a method which allows you to remove an item without searching through a linked list. It has remove(int index), which would have to scan the list to find the indexed entry, and it also has remove(Object o), which has to scan the list as well. Since a linked list implementation can save the necessary previous-item entry context while scanning, remove has equivalent complexity for singly- and doubly-linked lists. This state can be saved in an iterator, as well, so Iterator.remove() doesn't change this. So I don't think you can tell from remove performance.

My guess is that the "right" answer to this is to create several lists of different sizes and time the performance of .indexOf() and .lastIndexOf() when searching for the first or last object. Presuming that the implementation is doubly-linked and searches from the beginning of the list for .indexOf() and searches from the end for .lastIndexOf(), the performance will be length-dependent or length-independent.